# Custom Authentication provider does not work in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, custom-authentication

I want to add spring security(using Java config) into my application with custom authentication provider, however I cannot make it work. It seems that the authenticationProvider was not well configured, coz I cannot debug into the method authenticate(Authentication), and the println doesn't print anything. And every request responsed with 403.

Please anyone can help me with this, I've been struck by this for the whoele weekend.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider(){

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication arg0) throws AuthenticationException {
                System.out.println("authenticating...");
                return arg0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
                return true;
            }

         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The authenticate() function of the class must return an UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken instance if the authentication is successful or null otherwise.

**

> **The org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager and configure is (set its providers) to a custom
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
>   This should return on its authenticate method a Authentication, which
>   should be setted with the GrantedAuthority**

**

Here is a sample authentication manager code that sets authorities and returns an authentication object.

Can you try injecting the customAUthenticationProvider class you have and then use that in the configure method?

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

Are the web xml mappings in place for spring security?

```
   <listener>
   <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
 </listener>

 <!-- use the springSecurityFilterChain -->
<filter>

          <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>

        <filter-      class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   <!-- NOTE This does not specify its own configuration it is
     loaded by the ContextLoaderListener instead -->

   <!-- NOTE by default the filter name is used to
     look up the Spring Security Filter Chain if you like you
     can use any filter name you want, but you must specify
     the bean name instead in this instance. Since we use the
     springSecurityFilterChain as the filter name this is not
     necessary
<init-param>
    <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
    <param-value>springSecurityFilterChain</param-value>
</init-param> -->
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is a sample spring security project : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig

Comment: Thanks Paul, actually I have tried CustomAuthenticationProvider as a concrete class, however it doesn't work either.

Comment: is the configure method called at all?

Comment: just twant to confirm that the web.xml and configs are in place. I have also pasted a link to a sample spring security java config project..

Comment: I think the config class itself works properly, as i mentioned i got 403 for every request, and i can debug into the configure method when the application start up.

Comment: ahh..i c..If you are getting a 403 code, means that the user does not have the required roles. So, athentication could be the problem, is authorization.

Comment: yes, that what i need to do is implementing the authenticate method to grant proper role to the user. but it seems the method didnt execute at all. 
or elsewhere i need to add this function

Comment: Try thsi sample...https://javahunter.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/spring-security-3-custom-authentication-manager/

Comment: @songva i have added some info on authenticate method returning UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and a code sample. This might do the trick.